# How to create a new column through a old one with REGEX in BigQuery?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I would like to create a new column through an old one.

I have this column: `name`. It's a `String` column. I have this kind of data:

```
ALUMNNAME_SURNAME_CLASS_UNIVERSITY_YEAR_(16/09 - 22/09)
```

I would like to create new columns split each `_`.

In Google Sheets, I know how to do it (`INDEX(SPLIT(C2:C;"_");0;1...`) but how can I do it in `BigQuery`?

I understand it's something like this:

```
SELECT
   name,
   REGEXP_EXTRACT(name, regex) AS Name,
   REGEXTRACT(name, regex) AS Surname,
   ...
```

Could you help me to create the RegRx? I can't find how to divide each part.

Comment: Would each value in the column always have exactly 5 underscores?

Comment: Yes. All the values have the same format. I get to extract the first one with this:

^[a-zA-Z\ ]+ 

but i want to split all.

Answer (score 1):

In Standard SQL, we can try using the `SPLIT()` function:

```
SELECT
    SPLIT(input, '_')[OFFSET(0)] part1,
    SPLIT(input, '_')[OFFSET(1)] part2,
    SPLIT(input, '_')[OFFSET(2)] part3,
    SPLIT(input, '_')[OFFSET(3)] part4,
    SPLIT(input, '_')[OFFSET(4)] part5
FROM (SELECT "ALUMNNAME_SURNAME_CLASS_UNIVERSITY_YEAR_(16/09 - 22/09)" input)
```